# New foursquare posts (new platform) aren't showing

Tags: foursquare, platform

Has this features been removed? It won't show on the site or the app (official app) anymore...

Comment: What posts aren't you seeing? Are these posts from a connected app, or your friend's check-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind this... it was an error from the actual code.